# Find the maximum value of the matrix trace

Tags: linear-algebra

It is known that $A^2 + 3A = 2E$, where $A_{n\times n}$ is a square matrix over a field of real numbers and $n=5$.
E is identity matrix. Find the maximum value of the trace of matrix A.

My idea: suppose that exist $x\neq0$ $\Rightarrow$ $Ax = \lambda x$ and $A^2x = \lambda^2x$. After that I get a quadratic equation $\lambda^2+3\lambda-2 = 0$, where
$$ \lambda_{1,2} =  - \frac{3 \pm \sqrt{17}}{2}.$$
Are these $\lambda_{1,2}$ the eigenvalues of matrix A?

Does my idea correct and what should I do after?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: what about $A=\lambda_{max}E$ ?

Comment: I don't understand from what reasons it should be $A = \lambda_{max}E$. Should I  take  the matrix $A = \lambda_{max}E$, fill it in equation $ A^2 + 3A = 2E$ and check equality?

Comment: The trace is the sum of eigenvalues, so it is maximum $5\lambda_{max}$ for a matrix which would have $5$ times this particular eigenvalue (if it had the other eigenvalue, the trace would diminish). It happens that a multiple of the identity matrix works fine and the maximum is reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes: you have correctly deduced that the only possible eigenvalues of $A$ are $\frac{-3 \pm \sqrt{17}}{2}$. Indeed, if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then there exists an associated (by definition, non-zero) eigenvector $x$ such that $Ax = \lambda x$, so that
$$
(A^2 + 3A - 2E)x = 0 \implies (\lambda^2 + 3 \lambda - 2)x = 0 \implies \lambda^2 + 3\lambda - 2 = 0.
$$
Now, note that the trace of $A$ is equal to the sum of the eigenvalues of $A$. Thus, the trace of $A$ is maximized when all of the eigenvalues of $A$ are as large as possible, which is to say that all eigenvalues of $A$ are equal to $\frac{-3 + \sqrt{17}}{2}$.

Thus, the maximum possible value of the trace of $A$ is $n \cdot \frac{-3 + \sqrt{17}}{2}$.